# Need a little clarification about question on modulo arithematic

Tags: number-theory

My instructor has asked to find multiplicative inverse of $27 \pmod{80}$. I am not asking for solution here. But what is meaning of this $27\pmod{80}$? Is it that it is equivalence class in which $27$ element is there? Kindly clarify this. I am new to this modulo stuff.

Thanks

Comment: $$27\cdot3\equiv1\pmod{80}$$

Comment: By definition, $\,27\,$  has inverse $\,x\iff 27x\equiv 1\!\ \pmod{\!80}\ \, $ To solve it note that $\,1\equiv 81,\,$ which is divisible by $\,27.\,\,$ Generally you can use the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242)

Comment: The notation $27\pmod{80}$ indeed denotes the equivalence class of integers modulo $80$ to which $27$ belongs.

Comment: There are two mathematical notations in which you can write this. The first one is: $(27\bmod{80})=(107\bmod{80})=(187\bmod{80})=\ldots=((27+80k)\bmod{80})$. The second one is: $27\equiv107\equiv187\equiv\ldots\equiv27+80k\pmod{80}$.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee The OP is explicitly confused by the mod notation and is not asking for a solution.  Your terse answer which uses without explanation the same notation is rather unhelpful.

Comment: @ForgotALot You mean to say that question askes to find inverse of class which leaves remainder 27 when divided by 80

Answer (score 1):

A number $x$ satisfies the congruence $$\ x\equiv a\ \mod\ n\ $$ if and only if $n|x-a$. The inverse , if existent, is the number $y$ with $$\ xy\equiv 1\ \mod\ n$$

This inverse is unique modulo $n$ , but it only exists if $\ gcd(x,n)=1\ $.

Comment: Here it is 27(mod80). So a=27 and n=80. So as far as i understand this i first have to find x and then put in your second equation to find y